# macOS Server multiple network interfaces: interconnection?

Tags: networking, macos, macos-sierra

I have a mac server connected to two LANs over 2 thunderbolt to LAN adapters.

**GREEN** IP via DHCP in range 192.168.204.*
**BLUE** IP via DHCP in range 192.168.1.*

Everything works as I want it to, but I have some questions.

-Are **GREEN** and **BLUE** now somehow interconnected?

-Can members of **GREEN** or **BLUE** access the other network somehow?

We have a strict network separation rule for **GREEN** and **BLUE**. Do I violate it?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under *normal circumstances* traffic will not be able to flow from the green to the blue network unless you have IP routing enabled on the system. If IP routing is disabled it should not be possible for users to cross from one network to the other.

**However**, this is not really a secure setup because if someone can gain access to the server (such as an SSH session) through one of the networks they could then make a connection out from the server onto the other network. So no, it's not totally secure and would be an unacceptable interconnection between two networks which really need to remain securely separated.

As for a violation of a strict network separation rule that would depend on the specific rule or policy in place. You may or may not violate it depending on the specific rule.

Comment: Thank you. The rule is : "no physical connection between the networks"
Maybe I should disable all network administrative functions. So only physical access to the device can make any changes

Comment: Maybe. however if a single device is connected to both networks there will *always* be some security vulnerability that something could jump from one network to another through the device. In other words there is no totally safe way to do this. It is up to you and your network administrators to determine if a particular rule/policy is broken or whether the risk is acceptable. Also, if you found the answer helpful please mark it as accepted so that the question will stop popping up on the list of open questions.